# NetBeans Debugger Attach Configurations

Tags: debugging, netbeans, remote-debugging

**How can I remove the items in the list of the most recent debugger sessions?**  This shows up when you click the drop-down arrow inside the "Debug Project" button.
Where does NetBeans store this information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

probably somewhere in ~/.netbeans/nbversion/config/Preferences/

Comment: FYI, I found it in `config\Services\org-netbeans-modules-debugger-Settings.properties` under the `debugger.last_attaches.*` section. Also, apparently with NetBeans 7.2, in Windows, the data is now located here: `~\Application Data\NetBeans\7.2`